# how to hide canvas and rectangle in on_press event of Button in .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I have created a login screen in kivy and I want to hiding or disabling canvas and rectangle after pressing button,please help me. Here is my code

> :
>                 name: "cany"
>                 canvas.before:
>                       Color:
>                             rgba: 1,1,1,1
>                       Rectangle:
>                             size: self.size
>                             pos: self.pos
>                             source: 'rect4190.png'
>             Label:
>                   id:user_lbl
>                   text:"User Name: "
>                   color: .9,.1,.1,1
>                   pos: 40,400
>
> ```
>       TextInput:
>             id:username_txt
>             size: cm(4),cm(0.66)
>             pos: 125,437
>             write_tab: False
>             multiline: False
>
>       Label:
>             id:pass_lbl
>             text: 'Password:'
>             color: .9, 0.12, .1, 1
>             pos: 40,350
>
>       TextInput:
>             id:password_txt
>             size: cm(4),cm(0.66)
>             pos: 125,387
>             write_tab: False
>             multiline: False
>
>       Button:
>             id:btn_login
>             size: cm(2.33),cm(0.66)
>             text: 'Login'
>             pos:  160,200
>             focus: True
>             on_press:
>                   root.validate(username_txt.text,password_txt.text)
>                   user_lbl.opacity = 0
>                   pass_lbl.opacity = 0
>                   username_txt.opacity = 0
>                   password_txt.opacity = 0
>                   btn_login.opacity = 0
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your python file:

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
```

In your Login class in your python file:

```
canvas_opacity = NumericProperty(1, rebind=True)

def vanish_canvas(self):
    self.canvas_opacity = 0
```

In your kv file,

```
<LoginScreen>:
    name: "cany" 
    canvas.before: 
        Color: 
            rgba: 1,1,1, root.canvas_opacity
        Rectangle: 
            size: self.size 
            pos: self.pos 
            source: 'rect4190.png' 

    Button:
        text: 'clear canvas'
        on_press: root.clear_canvas()
```

What this does isn't remove the images but it makes everything that's part of the canvas in question invisible.

Canvas does have an inbuilt clear function but it seems that it will clear everything, including widgets you don't want to get rid of.

Comment: Thank you,I underestanding it,but why i cant fade it with a downwardly counter for loop?

Comment: It seems like you would have to use the animation features of kivy to make the fade an 'animation'. [See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446980/kivy-fade-in-animation)